# How can I POST x-www-form-urlencoded data from REST API plugin?

Tags: 8, plugins

In Drupal 8, the REST API plugin can have a serialization format, such as `xml` or `json`. This affects the accepted "request formats" for a resource.

Is it possible to add a format for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` handling for the REST plugin? or does this need to be handled in a form controller instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking into this, I found this solution to accept form encoded POST data and respond with JSON:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Encoder;

use Drupal\serialization\Encoder\JsonEncoder as SerializationJsonEncoder;

/**
 * Decodes form data and returns JSON.
 *
 * Simply respond to form format requests using the JSON encoder.
 */
class FormJsonEncoder extends SerializationJsonEncoder {

  /**
   * The formats that this Encoder supports.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected static $format = ['form'];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function decode($data, $format, array $context = array()) {
    parse_str($data, $result);
    return $result;
  }

}
```

and then add the encoder to the `example.services.yml`

```
services:
  serializer.encoder.form:
    class: Drupal\example\Encoder\FormJsonEncoder
    tags:
      - { name: encoder, format: form }
```

After that, the "Accepted request format" can be selected on the rest plugin config page:

*admin/config/services/rest/resource/example_rest_plugin/edit*

[image: form post format setting]