# How to configure a custom POST api to accept a request with Content-Type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in the header?

Tags: ajax, 9, page-controller

I created a controller in a custom module that accepts a `POST` request.
I have a setup such that I get a `POST` request from a third-party application server to this API. But the `POST` request has a `Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in the header.
And because of this I get the following error in the recent log messages:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException: No route found that matches "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in Drupal\Core\Routing\ContentTypeHeaderMatcher->filter() (line 49 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/ContentTypeHeaderMatcher.php).```

When I test the API using postman:

1. if I use the `Content-Type: "application/json"` in the header, the code inside the API is executed, and I get the correct response.
2. if I use the `Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, I get the same error.

I cannot configure the third party application server to change the `Content-Type`. So the only option for me is to configure the API to accept the `POST` request with the `Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. How can I do that?

Edited:
My class extends the class ResourceBase. Route definition of the controller. Also I am using drupal 8.

```
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "test_abc_callback",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom API for Test"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "create" = "/api/v1/test_callback",
 *   }
 * )
```

Comment: That's the default format for POST requests. What's in the route definition of the controller?

Comment: @4k4 I have edited the question to add the route definition. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a custom controller. For the original question you would need to define the method POST in a custom route. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/structure-of-routes

But you don't necessarily need a custom controller. You can add serializers to REST API for formats already defined in the Symfony request object:

[Request::initializeFormats](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AinitializeFormats)

```
protected static function initializeFormats()
{
    static::$formats = [
        'html' => ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml'],
        'txt' => ['text/plain'],
        'js' => ['application/javascript', 'application/x-javascript', 'text/javascript'],
        'css' => ['text/css'],
        'json' => ['application/json', 'application/x-json'],
        'jsonld' => ['application/ld+json'],
        'xml' => ['text/xml', 'application/xml', 'application/x-xml'],
        'rdf' => ['application/rdf+xml'],
        'atom' => ['application/atom+xml'],
        'rss' => ['application/rss+xml'],
        'form' => ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    ];
}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/serialization-api/adding-new-formats and [How can I POST x-www-form-urlencoded data from REST API plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268349/how-can-i-post-x-www-form-urlencoded-data-from-rest-api-plugin)